# How can I authenticate a web application running PaaS in Azure against Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-devops

I'm creating a web app for my company that I want to provide extra functionality for Visual Studio Team Services that's very business specific. We have some custom rules about how we want to setup and manage Work Items in Visual Studio Team Services. Is there I way that I can use delegated authentication with Azure Active Directory so that my web app can authenticate the user against Visual Studio Team Services and make calls and setup work items on the user's behalf ?

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with Azure Active Directory, refer to this link for details: [Use Active Directory for authentication in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-authentication-authorization/). But this only works when your VSTS accounts are backed by Azure Active Directory.

If your VSTS accounts are not backed by Azure Active Directory, I would recommend you to use [OAuth 2.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth) to authorize with Visual Studio Team Service.